# Exercise using pointers in C give ambiguous output

Tags: c, pointers

This is the code of my teacher:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo1(int xval){
    int x;
    x = xval;
    printf("Address of x: %p\nValue of x: %d\n", &x, x);
}
void foo2(int dummy){
    int y;
    printf("Address of y: %p\nValue of y: %d\n", &y, y);
}
int main(void){
    foo1(7);
    foo2(11);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output generated:

[image: screenshot of the output of the execution]

Anyone can explain me why?

Comment: `y` is uninitialized.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: Noting else used the stack between calling `foo1` and calling `foo2`. It's just an accident.

Comment: Why, oh why, do instructors give "assignments" like this one?  They don't teach any useful lesson,  They confuse the learners.  They lead to pointless questions (and pointless answers) here on SO.  They lead, in some nonzero percentage of cases, to people writing actual code that (deliberately or accidentally) depends on such quirks and happenstances.  Overall, just a big fat negative, lose-lose experience.  Hey, all you misguided C instructors out there: PLEASE STOP!  [Sorry for this unseemly outburst.  I know it won't change anything, but I feel a little better now.]

Comment: @SteveSummit for the sake of our sanity, lets assume it is some compiler/assembly language course and the teacher is trying to explain how stack frames work through this example. Or maybe it is a systems security course and the teacher is explaining how left over values on the stack can be used in case for exploiting a format string vulnerability. We can only hope.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, please post text rather than pictures of text.

Comment: Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stack after call                     stack after call 
to foo1()                            to foo2()
+----------------+                   +----------------+    |
| stack frame of |                   | stack frame of |    |
| main()         |                   | main()         |    v
++++++++++++++++++ <-- same addr --> ++++++++++++++++++   stack
| stack frame of |                   | stack frame of |   growth
| foo1()         |                   | foo2()         |
+----------------+                   +----------------+
```

Now the address of x in stack frame of foo1() is same as address of y in stack frame of foo2().

This is because both functions have same number and type of arguments and local variables (which are pushed onto stack). In call of foo1() the value in address of x (0x7fff63387a84 in your case) is set to 7. This value persists as there is no other function call between foo1() and foo2().

**NOTE** This answer is only for your understanding. You should not rely on the value of y as it is uninitialized (as pointed out in the previous comments). This is mere an accidental phenomena. I suggest you to go through how stack frames are formed.

Comment: Right -- this can be useful information when debugging, but one should (almost) never write code that depends on the layout of stack frames.  (The exception is for debugging utilities, like those that dump the stack frame on error.)